# Call function matching the button attribute

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using TypeScript how can I trigger a function matching the onclick attribute.

```
<button onclick="window.open('myapp://', '_system')">Goto App</button>
```

So that means whenever someone clicks on button above, I will call a JavaScript function to take the user to `www.google.com`

Please note that I don't have control over this button or else It would have attached a method on the onclick.

Comment: your question is not clearly,please give more code/fake code to describe your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have control over this button

- You can get access to the button using `document.querySelectorAll`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- Once you have access (e.g. in a variable `btn`) use `btn.addEventListener('click',()=>stuff)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener